# How to re-claim my uTorrent Remote Access computer name?

Tags: windows, utorrent

I enabled uTorrent Remote Access when I was using Windows 7. After upgrading to Windows 8, I installed uTorrent & restored its data & settings from backup. After that, uTorrent failed to recognize this computer saying the username has already been claimed. I can always use new computer name, but I want to use my old computer name. I have the password. How to re-claim my old computer name?

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like uTorrent messed up your backup. Try resetting your settings in uTorrent to default. If that doesn't work then try uninstalling and then reinstalling. Then set up your remote configuration again. That way you retain the computer name you want. All uTorrent settings are able to be reset. It doesn't take much to set up the remote. So in the future backup your settings without remote enabled. that way you don't have to redo all your settings when the remote configuration gets messed up.

Comment: With new install, there's no way to claim that username...

Comment: he is talking about computer name. you can change that to whatever you want. if he wants to keep his computer name with uTorrent then he need to re-setup his remote settings. they are self contained in uTorrent. He was just hoping to recover his settings with uTorrent so he doesn't have to do it manually again. But it isn't working for him because there is something messed up in his back up. if he resets his settings and reconfigures it the old information will be gone. He will be able to keep his name of his Computer.

Comment: Excuse me, you are talking about.

Comment: If my answer seems to not be good for you then you can email Utorrent staff at remote@utorrent.com. They Might even be able to fix it for you without resetting your settings. Did you do the security question the first time you set up? Then they will be better for assisting. As remote logging in is through their site.

Comment: With fully fresh setup, I am encountering the same problem (I just tested it in a virtual computer).

Comment: then you need to email them at remote@utorrent.com as authentication is actually done through their website.

Comment: They aren't replying...

Comment: There should a be a UTSERVER.config file that holds all of these settings.  If I was at home I would be able to open it up and see if its any help to you, but since I'm not... That part is up to you.